# Comparing cell content against a variable in free pascal

Tags: freepascal

is there a way to compare the content of a cell in a grid against the content of a variable.

I need to compare cell 0,1 and if it's value is lower (or higher) than variable x then something happens.

I'm using Lazarus and a StringGrid.

Comment: In this question is missing what IDE are you using (Lazarus ?) and if so what grid are you using (StringGrid ?).

Comment: @TLama: Sorry, you are right. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (for integer values, but can easily be modified for another ordinal types). You can follow the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10820309/2) of this post as well:

```
uses
  Math;

function CompareValueEx(StringGrid: TStringGrid; const Column, Row: Integer;
  const Value: Integer; out Relationship: TValueRelationship): Boolean;
var
  Output: Integer;
begin
  Result := TryStrToInt(StringGrid.Cells[Column, Row], Output);
  if Result then
    Relationship := CompareValue(Value, Output);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Relationship: TValueRelationship;
begin      
  I := 111;
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 2] := '112';
  if CompareValueEx(StringGrid1, 1, 2, I, Relationship) then
  begin
    case Relationship of
      EqualsValue: ShowMessage('The values are the same');
      LessThanValue: ShowMessage('The I value is less than in cell [1;2]');
      GreaterThanValue: ShowMessage('The I value is greater than in cell [1;2]');
    end;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('The value in cell [1;2] is not a valid integer value!');
end;
```